# How can I slow my Javascript function to create an expanding circle animation?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to create an animation to practice JavaScript, where a circle begins at the middle of the page, slowly expanding outwards. However, while trying to use the setTimeout function or Promises to slow down the loop and continually draw a new slightly larger circle, the page goes from blank to a fully expanded circle.

I have tried to slow down a for loop which would draw the circle with an incrementing radius, including the methods described here- https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-sleep/

Here is one way that I have tried -

```
function new_circle() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


  ctx.fillStyle = '#3483eb';
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#3483eb';

  for (i=0; i<(canvas.width/2); i++) {

    setTimeout(function(){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, i, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();  
      ctx.stroke();
    },1000);    
  }

}
```

The expansion is not seen, instead the screen goes from white to blue. The delay happens between this transition, but the circle appears to fully expand rather be drawn again with a radius 1 pixel larger as expected.

Comment: all the setTimeouts are set to trigger almost at exactly the same time. By the way, viven the "jitter" introduced into some browsers timings (to circumvent some potential security issues), you may even end up with things going out of sequence! You'll also find that by the time the codes inside the setTimeout is run, all values of `i` will be `canvas.width/2`

Comment: Typically instead of a loop that can get out of sequence like this you'll want a recursive `requestAnimationFrame` call that calculates the canvas width/height based on how much time has elapsed since the animation started and then exits without the recursive call once the animation's expected time is up. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/208138 for a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the for loop will set all the iterations to run in 1 second, not 1 second after each other, but one second from almost the same starting point

What you need to do is to begin each iteration when the previous one has ended

You could use setInterval, but that can get messy

calling setTimeout inside a setTimeout callback function to self-call the function is the way I'd go

```
function new_circle() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


    ctx.fillStyle = '#3483eb';
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#3483eb';

    var fn = function(i) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, i, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();  
        ctx.stroke();
        i++;
        if(i < canvas.width/2) {
            setTimeout(fn, 1000, i + 1)
        }
    }
    setTimeout(fn, 1000, 0);
}
```

but, if you want smooth animation, with a known animation time, you'd use requestAnimationFrame, but that has an "interval" of 16.6ms (60 frames per second) - so, would run about 60 times faster than the code you tried to write in your question - you could use it though with a fairly simple rewrite of your code

e.g.

```
function new_circle() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


    ctx.fillStyle = '#3483eb';
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#3483eb';

    var startTime = 0;
    var animationTime = 5; // seconds
    var fn = function(time) {
        if (startTime) {
            var t = (time - startTime) / 1000;
            if (t > animationTime) {
                t = animationTime;
            }
            var i = canvas.height / 2 * t / animationTime;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, i, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.fill();  
            ctx.stroke();
            if(t < animationTime) {
                requestAnimationFrame(fn);
            }
        } else { // first call to requestAnimationFrame sets the start time
            startTime = time;
            requestAnimationFrame(fn);
        }
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(fn);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. However, in your first solution, wondering why the second setTimeout function (outside of fn) is necessary? I believe just calling fn(0) instead has the same effect?

Comment: because your original code attempts to do that, i.e. the very first iteration (in your code all iterations) is done after one second

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close, just need to switch out to `setInterval`. Both `setTimeout` and `setInterval` return an id that you can use to cancel it out. In this case I keep track of it until the circle gets to a certain size, and then I call `clearInterval` to cancel out the job.

```js
function new_circle() {

  var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


  ctx.fillStyle = '#3483eb';
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#3483eb';

  let i = 0;

  const intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    if (i === (canvas.width / 2)) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    } else {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, i++, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }, 50);
}

new_circle()
```

```html
<canvas height="100" width="100"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use recursion to achieve this:

```js
function drawPartial(ctx, i) {
  if (i >= (canvas.width / 2)) {
    return
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, i, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    drawPartial(ctx, i + 1);
  }, 1000);
}

function new_circle() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


  ctx.fillStyle = '#3483eb';
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#3483eb';

  drawPartial(ctx, 0)

}

new_circle();
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=200 height=250></canvas>
```